# Receiving only one byte in Serial Port - Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**The situation**

I have a scanner that has been working with a compiled application which I don't have the source. It still works and can be tested to make sure the scanner is working. I need to convert the data entry process to my web based system.

So I'm building a chrome app that read serial port information incoming from the com port. I first tried setting it up with a com port emulator and a virtual null modem. This allowed me to test the connection and the receive data. I can't find why I am  receiving only 1 byte.

**The problem**

When I connected to the actual scanner, I am able to connect without any issue, but when I receive the dataArray it's only one byte long. After reveiving the first data, I'm unable to receive any other data until I restart the connection.

**The Code**

```
var connectionId = -1;
var e_dtr, e_rts, e_dcd, e_cts, e_ri, e_dsr;
var dtr, rts;

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    chrome.serial.getDevices(function(objs,arg2){
        chrome.serial.connect(objs[0].path, {ctsFlowControl:true}, onConnect)
    });
});

chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(function(info){
    chrome.serial.getInfo(info.connectionId, output);
    var uint8View = new Uint8Array(info.data);
    var value = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8View);
    console.log(value);
});

chrome.serial.onReceiveError.addListener(function(info){
    var uint8View = new Uint8Array(info.data);
    var value = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8View);
    console.log(value);
});

function readSignals() {
    chrome.serial.getControlSignals(connectionId,onGetControlSignals);
}

function onSetControlSignals(result) {
    console.log("onSetControlSignals: " + result);
};

function changeSignals() {
    chrome.serial.setControlSignals(connectionId, { dtr: dtr, rts: rts }, onSetControlSignals);
}

function onGetControlSignals(signals) {
    console.log(signals);
}

function onConnect(connectionInfo) {
    console.log(connectionInfo);
    if (!connectionInfo) {
        console.log('Could not open');
        return;
    }
    connectionId = connectionInfo.connectionId;
    console.log('Connected');

    dtr = false;
    rts = false;
    changeSignals();

    setInterval(readSignals, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Do you have the documentation for the scanner itself? Setting up all the connection properties on those things can be tricky.

Comment: @Xan Sadly no. I know for sure that the Baud rate, data bits, parity and stop bit settings are correct because it works with the other software.